# What dependency am I missing for org.springframework.mock.web?

Tags: java, spring, spring-web

I am trying to use `MockMultipartFile` in existing source code for Egads but I keep getting this error: `package org.springframework.mock.web does not exist`

Here is the updated pom file:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.yahoo.egads</groupId>
  <artifactId>egads</artifactId>

  <name>EGADS Anomaly Detection System</name>
  <description>EGADS system, consumes time series and outputs anomalies.</description>
  <version>0.4.0</version>

  <organization>
    <name>Yahoo Inc.</name>
    <url>https://www.yahoo.com/</url>
  </organization>
  <inceptionYear>2015</inceptionYear>

  <developers>
    <developer>
      <organization>Yahoo Inc.</organization>
      <organizationUrl>https://www.yahoo.com/</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
  </developers>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>GPL V3</name>
      <url>https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <issueManagement>
    <system>Github</system>
    <url>https://github.com/yahoo/egads/issues</url>
  </issueManagement>

  <ciManagement>
    <system>Travis</system>
    <url>https://travis-ci.org/yahoo/egads</url>
  </ciManagement>

  <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
          <id>bintray-yahoo-egads</id>
          <name>yahoo-egads</name>
          <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/yahoo/maven/egads;publish=1</url>
      </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <properties>
    <spring-boot.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
  </properties>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>bintray-yahoo-maven</id>
      <name>bintray</name>
      <url>http://yahoo.bintray.com/maven</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>bintray-yahoo-maven</id>
      <name>bintray-plugins</name>
      <url>http://yahoo.bintray.com/maven</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.lbordowitz.openforecast</groupId>
        <artifactId>openforecast</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.16</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- TEST DEPENDENCIES -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.lbordowitz.openforecast</groupId>
          <artifactId>openforecast</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>jfree</groupId>
          <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>jfree</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.json</groupId>
          <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TEST DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

           <plugin>
             <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
               <descriptorRefs>
                 <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
               </descriptorRefs>
             </configuration>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.5.2</version>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                  <version>1.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.8.2</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>deploy</id>
                  <phase>deploy</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>

              <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0</version>
              <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The end goal for using `MockMultiPartFile` is to convert the path of a file from a command line argument into a multipart file. But I am unable to add this package to my project as of now.

I want to know what other items I need to add to the pom file in order to use this package in my project. Thank you.

Comment: org.springframework:spring-test. But your dependencies don't make any sense. You're mixing multiple versions of spring framework artifacts. Read the documentation of spring-boot, and use the spring-initializr, to know how to properly use the dependency management pllugin, instead of incorrectly defining them all by yourself.

Comment: I have org.springframework:spring-test already though? @JBNizet

Comment: Nope. It's only listed (twice!) in dependencyManagement. Not in dependencies. But again, restart from scratch, as I advised in my previous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a mess in your Spring Framework dependencies. Remove the specific `<version>` tags and let `spring-boot-starter-parent` mange the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You are trying to use Spring Framework 3.X, 4.X, 5.X (from Spring Boot 2.X) components at the same time, these are not compatible!

Most likely one of the 3.X dependencies is downgrading `spring-test` to version which doesn't have package `org.springframework.mock.web`. You can confirm this by inspecting `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: Even worse there is even `spring-mock` which is a spring 2.0 dependency.